# JNA - java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError on Ubuntu

Tags: java, ubuntu, java-native-interface, jna

I am trying to call my shared library on Ubuntu on an Amazon EC2 instance
The same code works 100% fine on windows but on Ubuntu - I am getting a java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError when I try to run it

When I run ldd on my shared library - all dependencies appear to be satisfied

```
root@ip-172-31-14-36:/var/lib/tomcat8/conf# ldd /tmp/dll/linux/v1/release/myConvertor.so
        linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffed4ffd000)
        libQt5Widgets.so.5 => /tmp/dll/linux/v1/release/libQt5Widgets.so.5 (0x00007fa81daff000)
        libQt5Gui.so.5 => /tmp/dll/linux/v1/release/libQt5Gui.so.5 (0x00007fa81d2ec000)
        libQt5Xml.so.5 => /tmp/dll/linux/v1/release/libQt5Xml.so.5 (0x00007fa81d0b0000)
        libQt5Network.so.5 => /tmp/dll/linux/v1/release/libQt5Network.so.5 (0x00007fa81cd57000)
        libQt5Core.so.5 => /tmp/dll/linux/v1/release/libQt5Core.so.5 (0x00007fa81c610000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fa81c3e6000)
        libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007fa81c064000)
        libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007fa81bd5a000)
        libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007fa81bb44000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fa81b77a000)
        libgobject-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0 (0x00007fa81b526000)
        libgthread-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgthread-2.0.so.0 (0x00007fa81b324000)
        librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007fa81b11c000)
        libglib-2.0.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0 (0x00007fa81ae0a000)
        libXext.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXext.so.6 (0x00007fa81abf8000)
        libX11.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6 (0x00007fa81a8be000)
        libGL.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1 (0x00007fa81a64b000)
        libicui18n.so.54 => /usr/lib/libicui18n.so.54 (0x00007fa81a1f7000)
        libicuuc.so.54 => /usr/lib/libicuuc.so.54 (0x00007fa819e66000)
        libicudata.so.54 => /usr/lib/libicudata.so.54 (0x00007fa81843c000)
        libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007fa818238000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x0000559ebb9c1000)
        libffi.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libffi.so.6 (0x00007fa81802f000)
        libpcre.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3 (0x00007fa817dbf000)
        libxcb.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1 (0x00007fa817b9c000)
        libexpat.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1 (0x00007fa817973000)
        libxcb-dri3.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-dri3.so.0 (0x00007fa817770000)
        libxcb-present.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-present.so.0 (0x00007fa81756c000)
        libxcb-sync.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-sync.so.1 (0x00007fa817365000)
        libxshmfence.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxshmfence.so.1 (0x00007fa817162000)
        libglapi.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglapi.so.0 (0x00007fa816f32000)
        libXdamage.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdamage.so.1 (0x00007fa816d2f000)
        libXfixes.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXfixes.so.3 (0x00007fa816b29000)
        libX11-xcb.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11-xcb.so.1 (0x00007fa816926000)
        libxcb-glx.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-glx.so.0 (0x00007fa81670d000)
        libxcb-dri2.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-dri2.so.0 (0x00007fa816508000)
        libXxf86vm.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXxf86vm.so.1 (0x00007fa816301000)
        libdrm.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdrm.so.2 (0x00007fa8160f0000)
        libXau.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6 (0x00007fa815eeb000)
        libXdmcp.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so.6 (0x00007fa815ce5000)
```

My code to load the shared library is as follows

```
String dllLocation = "/tmp/dll/linux/v1/release/myConvertor.so";
canvasConversionInterface = (CanvasConversionInterface) Native.loadLibrary(dllLocation, CanvasConversionInterface.class);
```

I have the following system properties set on tomcat

```
jna.library.path="/tmp/dll/linux/v1/release"
jna.debug_load=true
```

Here is the error I get when I try call that line above to load the shared library

```
Looking in classpath from WebappClassLoader
  context: ROOT
  delegate: false
----------> Parent Classloader:
java.net.URLClassLoader@52d278a0
 for /com/sun/jna/linux-x86-64/libjnidispatch.so
Found library resource at jar:file:/var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/jna-4.5.0.jar!/com/sun/jna/linux-x86-64/libjnidispatch.so
Looking for library '/tmp/dll/linux/v1/release/myConvertor.so'
Adding paths from jna.library.path: "/tmp/dll/linux/v1/release"
Trying /tmp/dll/linux/v1/release/myConvertor.so
Adding system paths: [/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu, /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu, /lib64, /usr/lib, /lib, /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfakeroot, /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa]
Trying /tmp/dll/linux/v1/release/myConvertor.so
Looking for version variants
Looking in classpath from WebappClassLoader
  context: ROOT
  delegate: false
----------> Parent Classloader:
java.net.URLClassLoader@52d278a0
 for /tmp/dll/linux/v1/release/myConvertor.so
2017-10-02 13:27:21 [jmsNewPublicationQueueMessageListenerContainer-1] WARN  o.s.j.l.DefaultMessageListenerContainer - Execution of JMS message listener failed, and no ErrorHandler has been set.
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Unable to load library '/tmp/dll/linux/v1/release/myConvertor.so': Native library (tmp/dll/linux/v1/release/myConvertor.so) not found in resource path ([...
```

...

I can verify that all paths mentioned above are accurate

Can anyone offer any ideas on what I could try next to try and get this working?

Thank you
Damien

Comment: After setting the library path, try loading just `"myConvertor"`

Comment: tried that but it has  the same outcome unfortunately

Comment: And the EC2 instance is running a 64-bit Java runtime?

Comment: it is yes - openjdk version "1.8.0_131"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_131-8u131-b11-2ubuntu1.16.04.3-b11)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.131-b11, mixed mode)

Comment: Try naming the file `libmyConvertor.so`, then load `myConvertor`. JNA automatically adds prefixes and extensions depending on the platform - this may be the issue right now.

Comment: tried that but with no joy unfortunately.

Comment: would you know of a simple dll that has a windows and linux variation that I could try to test out on my platform?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with the shared library and it was using OpenCV
After talking with the C++ developer - we figured out that the OpenCV dependency could be removed from the Library
Once we removed this and tried again - everything worked perfectly